# Text Disappears when enter is pressed in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have a RichTextBox. Inside the box I have used FlowDocument and run  as like below,

```
<RichTextBox  Margin="0"  Height="75" Width="300" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <FlowDocument>
       <Paragraph>
          <Run x:Name="remarksText" Text="{Binding BookName,
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
       </Paragraph>
   </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Initially I set some value in BookName property. It showed correctly. When I try to edit it in runtime, after focussing the cursor I have pressed enter button in this case and existing value got disappeared. Does anyone know what is the reason for this issue.

Is this an issue or behaviour related to either RichTextBox or FlowDocument?

Thanks,

Sharp

Comment: Maybe it didn't disappeared but you've moved to the new line and the previous text moved up? Have you checked that before?

Comment: yes I also checked that but it shows only empty box in view only cursor has moved to next line.

Comment: When you press enter with your selection in the middle of a Run, the editor will make another paragraph with a run in it.  Something like `<Paragraph><Run Text="{Binding ..}" /></Paragraph><Paragraph><Run Text="??" /></Paragraph>`

I assume the text manipulation that happens during this operation has no  idea what to do with your binding so it is empty.  I do not know what the solution could be.

Answer (score 1):

Same question,i have found a solution,assume your xaml is:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name = RTB PreviewKeyDown = "RTB_PreviewKeyDown">
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text = "{Binding SomeProperty,Mode = TwoWay}"/>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

And in cs code,implement RTB_PreviewKeyDown and a InsertText medthod:

```
private void RTB_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {                
        InsertText(RTB, "\r\n");
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

public static void InsertText(RichTextBox rtb, string content)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
    {
        rtb?.BeginChange();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rtb.Selection.Text))
        {
            rtb.Selection.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        var tp = rtb.CaretPosition.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        rtb.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun(content);
        rtb.CaretPosition = tp;
        rtb.EndChange();
        Keyboard.Focus(rtb);
    }
}
```

Hope this solution is working.

Comment: This should be mark as answer